# Make [react-state-management] a synonym of [react-state]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I recently noticed the tags [react-state-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-state-management) and [react-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-state) and wondered if they are the same.

Many questions with [react-state-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-state-management) also have [react-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-state). The tags are similar and have the same meaning, so it makes sense to synonymize or even merge them.

What do you think?